# Объединение точек на изображении ломанной линией

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть матрица, состоящая из нулей и единиц, так выглядит ее тепловая карта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно спроецировать границу между этими областями на изображение, для этого я разбиваю матрицу на сетку, расстояние между точками (dx и dy) беру 30 пикселей. Затем "пограничные" точки я записываю в список, и пытаюсь провести между этими же точками на изображении (изображение имеет тот же размер, что матрица) отрезки. Ищу для каждой точки ближайшую и провожу отрезок. Вот код этого алгоритма:

```
def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p2[1] - p1[1])**2)

def find_nearest_point(point, points):
    min_distance = float('inf')
    nearest_point = None
    for p in points:
        if p != point:
            dist = distance(point, p)
            if dist < min_distance:
                min_distance = dist
                nearest_point = p
    return nearest_point

def draw_lines(points, path):
    img = Image.open(path)
    draw = ImageDraw(img)
    for point in points:
        nearest_point = find_nearest_point(point, points)
        draw.line((point[0], point[1], nearest_point[0], nearest_point[1]), fill='red', width=2)

    img.show()
```

Вот что получается в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Мне необходимо соединить все линии ломанной. Что я делаю не так?
Вот матрица из приведенного примера:

Comment: Если ожидается что в результате должна получиться кусочно линейная **функция**, отсортируйте точки по *x* и соедините последовательно.

Comment: Если вы хотите строить произвольные контуры, то https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares / https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares.

Comment: Matplotlib умеет: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html

Answer (score 0):

В этой задаче лучше использовать цикл while для перебора точек:

```
def draw_lines(points, path):
    img = Image.open(path)
    draw = ImageDraw(img)
    while(len(points) > 1):
        point = points[0]
        nearest_point = find_nearest_point(point, points)
        draw.line((point[0], point[1], nearest_point[0], nearest_point[1]), fill='red', width=2)

        points.remove(point)
    img.show()
```